# Problem with recognizing NTFS partition - two hard drives Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem

I have two hard drives in my computer: 480 GB SSD and 1 TB HDD.
Primary disk is the SSD on which I have systems (Ubuntu and Windows10) - everything is fine with it. The problem is with disk # 2 - 1 TB HDD.

Ubuntu recognizes the HDD drive, detects the capacity correctly. THE PROBLEM IS: Badly detects partitions on this disk. There are two ntfs partitions on the windows. The first 100 GB and the second the rest, i.e. around 830 GB.
Ubuntu recognizes this so that ONLY ONE partition is 931.40 GB, 100 GB is available (that is, the first partition) and the rest (where the second partition should be) is 'unallocated space'.

I would like to be able to access all the data on the HDD from within Ubuntu.

[image: This is what it looks like in GParted.]

[image: fdisk report]

Comment: Apparently LDM is a *logical* partition scheme from Microsoft for Windows. You might still be able to mount it. I would discourage using this partition scheme for a dual boot config or if you ever intend to mount the partitions anywhere but Windows. These days with GPT allowing you to have 128 partitions, LDM seems like a poor choice across the board.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427372/windows-spanned-disks-ldm-restoration-with-linux/22108676#22108676

Comment: @Nmath ok, so it would be worth backing up this data and reformatting it?  What system is the best to format the disk to use data in Linux and windows?

Comment: If it were me, I would use the "Disks" app to format (erase) the disk so it uses the GPT partition scheme (instead of MBR).  That way you don't need to have any extended partitions: Those are only needed to get around the limit of 4 total partitions with MBR.  File system for partitions is a bit more tricky.  Since you need to access the data from Windows and Ubuntu, NTFS or exFAT are probably the best options since Windows doesn't read/write to ext4. Both are pretty well supported by the linux kernel 5.4+, but you might want to do some research into the subtle differences between the two

Comment: I did as you wrote.  I erased everything and created two NTFS partitions by gparted and everything works great.  Both on windows and on Linux.  thank you, topic to be closed.